# Powershell - .csv split strings

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to use powershell for extracting email addresses from a .csv file.
Each row in the .csv may have none or more emails separated by ",".

f.e.
Email
info@domain.com, email@domain.com, person@contonso.com
something@domain.com

My goal is to write it that way so I can get the "info@*" from the row if it is present + 1 extra email from the row if it is present. If there is no "info@*" get at least 1 or 2 emails from that row.

Here is the fracture of the code, where I am manually able to say on what position is what email, but I am not able to get this part to work in the for cycle which I could use to enumerate the number of occurences as it appears I cannot convert it to int at all.

```
$Occurrences = $email.Split(",").GetUpperBound(0);
[int]$Occurrences

$data = Import-Csv -path $path
foreach($contact in $data)
{
    $email = $contact.Email

    if($email.Contains("info"))
    {
        $emailSplit = $contact.Email.Split(",")
        $Occurrences = $email.Split(",").GetUpperBound(0);
        [int]$Occurrences
        $name = $domainSplit[0]
        for([int]$i = 0;-lt $Occurrences.ToInt32(); $i++)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For better understanding, please show us the first 3 lines of the input csv file. Now we don't know if the email addresses (comma separated) are written out as single quoted string, or if the csv uses some other delimiter character?

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear, but the examlpe is under f.e. it is comma separated. Email represents the header, then there is one row containing 3emails sparated by comma and then another row with just 1 email on it

Comment: Yes, but then, if the various emails are written out comma separated but NOT as single quoted string, you will end up with more (nameless) columns because there would be no difference in the field delimiter and the items in that single Email field. That's why I asked to gine an example. Of course sanitized and real names and emails 'bogussed-out'

Comment: My intention is to have 2 variables ready, and fill them with info@whatver.com if it is present, and then any other email from the row and drop the rest. Once these 2 vars are filled, I will just write it to another .csv each on a new row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a valid CSV Format. Cant you export the data via JSON from the datasource?

You need to split the single lines and then do your operations

```
$data = Get-Content -path $path
for($i=1; $i -lt $data.Length; $i++)
{
    $emailSplit = [array]$data[$i].Split(",")
    for($j = 0; $j -lt $emailSplit.Length; $j++) {
        <#do your operation here... 
        loop once through the elements, check for info@, and then assign them accoringly...
        #>

    }
}
```

V2:

```
$data = Get-Content -path $path
for($i=1; $i -lt $data.Length; $i++)
{
    $emailSplit = [array]$data[$i].Split(",")
    Write-Host ('Results for line: ' + $i)
    $infoFound = $false
    for($j = 0; $j -lt $emailSplit.Length; $j++) {
        if($emailSplit[$j] -match 'Info@*') {
                                            $infoFound = $true
                                            $infoPos = $j
                                            }
    }
    [array]$results = $emailSplit[0]
    $results += $emailSplit[-1]
    if($infoFound) {
        if($infoPos = 0) {$results[1] = $emailSplit[$infoPos]}
        else {$results[0] = $emailSplit[$infoPos]}

    }
    Write-Host ('Element1: ' + $results[0] + ' Element2: ' + $results[1])
}
```

Comment: unfortuntaly, this is one of the column of bigger .csv and the email header just contains multiple email addresses separated by comma... thanks for your suggestion, will try it

Comment: your code returns me each row multiplied by the amount of emails on it :-( am lost

Comment: can you please add a full example of some lines including all relevant scenarios?

Comment: sure, imagine this being the .csv

header: Email
row1: info@contonso.com, email@contonso.com, person@contonso.com
row2: person@domain.com
row3: info@gmail.com, person@gmail.com
etc....

I would need to extract from each row the info@ contact and write it to another file on it's own row and then add 1 more email from the row to the other file as well if it exists.

Comment: you are the best! thank you very much :-) <3 and sorry if the question was not clear at first place